# How can I calculate the cut-off frequency of an RC filter?

Tags: circuit-analysis, low-pass, passive-filter, cutoff-frequency, calculate

I tred to calculate the cut-off frequency of the circuit below.

When I think of two resistors as parallel and calculate them in a built-in RC filter calculator, I found a 51.0112 Hz cut-off frequency. How can I verify this result? Does it make sense?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you convert the 5 volt source and series 10 kΩ resistor to a current source and parallel resistor you get a CC of 5 mA and, a parallel resistor of 10 kΩ. The 10 kΩ resistor is now parallel with the 40 kΩ resistor.

So, if you combined those resistors and converted the 5 mA current source and combined parallel resistor (8 kΩ) back to a voltage source you inevitably get a series resistor of 8 kΩ and, that forms a low-pass cut-off with the 390 nF capacitor of: -

$$\dfrac{1}{2\pi\cdot 8000 \cdot 390\text{n}} = \text{51.01 Hz}$$

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. The full working -

As the frequency increases, the impedance presented by the capacitor decreases. The -3dB cut-off point for this filter occurs when the output is 0.4x the input, because the DC value is 0.8x
For a resistor divider, the output is R1/R1+R2, substituting XR1, meaning the impedance of the resistor and capacitor in parallel, for R1, and 10k for R2, we can rearrange to 
XR1/(XR1+10k) = 0.4

XR1 = 0.4 * XR1 + 4k
XR1 * (1-0.4) = 4k
XR1 = 4k / (1 - 0.4) = 4k / 0.6 = 6.67 kOhm

Now we need to solve for the capacitor impedance to get this value, they are in parallel so
 6.67k = (R1*XC) / (R1+XC)
6.67k * (R1 + XC) = R1 * XC 
6.67k * R1 = (R1 * XC) - 6.67k * XC = XC(R1-6.67) 
XC = (6.67k * R1) / (R1 - 6.67k) = (6.67k * 40k) / (40k - 6.67k) = 8k

Finally, we now need to solve the frequency, where XC = 1 / (2 * pi * f * C)
f = 1 / ( 2 * pi * C * XC ) = 1 / (2 * 3.14 * 390n * 8k ) = 51.03Hz
I'd expect the <0.02Hz difference is rounding error on my part.

It's a pretty quick one to simulate and check your work with, in this case, the simulator agrees with us, giving an answer of 51.0281Hz
[image: circuit simulation]

Answer (score 2):

If you convert the voltage source and two resistors into their Thevenin equivalent, then the answer to your question becomes clearer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJwg64.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now replace that system in the original circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2GxTy.png)</sup>

Immediately two things become apparent. First, at low frequencies the signal is attenuated by a factor of \$\frac{4}{5}\$, and second, the cut-off frequency is:

$$ f_C = \frac{1}{2\pi \times 8k\Omega \times 390nF} = 51Hz $$

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's analyze this circuit. The transfer function is given by:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{V}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\space\text{||}\space\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\left(\text{R}_2\space\text{||}\space\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)}=\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{sCR}_1\text{R}_2+\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag1$$

Where \$\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\$.

When working with sinusoidal inputs we know that we can write \$\text{s}:=\text{j}\omega\$ where \$\text{j}^2=-1\$. So we get:

$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\text{R}_2}{\sqrt{\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)^2+\left(\omega\text{CR}_1\text{R}_2\right)^2}}\tag2$$

Now, let's analyze a few cases:

1. \$\omega\space\to\space0\$:
   $$\lim_{\omega\space\to\space0}\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag3$$
2. \$\omega\space\to\space\infty\$:
   $$\lim_{\omega\space\to\space\infty}\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=0\tag4$$
3. When is \$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|\$ at a maximum:
   $$\frac{\partial\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|}{\partial\hat{\omega}}=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\hat{\omega}=0\tag5$$

So, we get:

$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|=\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag6$$

So, the cut-off frequency is:

$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\space\Longrightarrow\space\omega=\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}{\text{C}\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}\tag7$$

So, using your values we get:

$$2\pi\text{f}=\frac{\displaystyle10\cdot1000+40\cdot1000}{\displaystyle390\cdot10^{-9}\cdot10\cdot1000\cdot40\cdot1000}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{f}=\frac{6250}{39 \pi }\approx51.0112\space\text{Hz}\tag8$$